# Rails - Pundit with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, scopes

I am trying to figure out how to write pundit permissions in my Rails 4 app.

I have an article model, with an article policy. The article policy has:

```
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, record, scope)
      @scope = scope
      super(user, record)
    end

    class Scope < Scope         
      def resolve
        if user == article.user
          scope.where(user_id: user_id)
        elsif approval_required?
          scope.where(article.state_machine.in_state?(:review)).(user.has_role?(:org_approver)) 
        else
          article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)  
        end 
      end
    end 

    # TO DO - check if this is correct - I'm not sure.
    # I now think I don't need the index actions because I have changed the action in the articles controller to look for policy scope.
    # def index?  
    #   article.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)
    # end

    def article
      record
    end
```

The articles controller has:

```
def index
  @articles = policy_scope(Article)
  # query = params[:query].presence || "*"
  # @articles = Article.search(query)
end
```

I am following the pundit documents relating to scopes and trying to figure out why the index action shown in the policy documents isn't working for me. I have tried the following (as shown in the docs):

```
 <% policy_scope(@user.articles).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
```

but I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `article' for #<ArticlePolicy::Scope:0x007fff08ae9f48>
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

I'm not sure that @user.articles is right. In my construct, articles belong to users, but in my index action, I want to show every user the articles that my scopes allow them to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your action in controller.

```
@articles = policy_scope(Article).all
```

It will get all the articles. If you want to get the articles based on search params, you can try this.

```
@q = policy_scope(Article).search(params[:query])
@articles = @q.result
```

Comment: @Bllal - thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but I still get the same error message as above.

Comment: Can you please check if record variable contains the respective article? I think it should contain the article record.

Comment: Hi @Bllal - I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: I mean use record instead of article in scope:

Comment: Hi @Bllal - I tried this, thanks for the suggestion, but it doesnt make any difference. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to explicitly set article as an accessor in the Scope class as the error indicates that it doesn't recognise 'article'. Try something like

```
attr_accessor :article
```

set it in an initialize method and you can probably do away with the article method.

```
def initialize(record)
  @article = record
end
```

Comment: Hi @margo thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but I still get the same error message as I showed above.